# How to I make this code to print the highest value(s) in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, max

How to I make this code to print the highest value(s) in the array?

Examples ([view detailled screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHfB8.jpg)):

- Player 1 Score = 1
- Player 2 Score = 2
- Player 3 Score = 1

  > Player 2 is the winner.
- Player 1 Score = 1
- Player 2 Score = 3
- Player 3 Score = 3

  > Player 2 is the winner.
  >   Player 3 is the winner.
- Player 1 Score = 1
- Player 2 Score = 1
- Player 3 Score = 1

  > Player 1 is the winner.
  >   Player 2 is the winner.
  >   Player 3 is the winner.`

So far, here is my attempt of code:

```
/**
 * [algorithm description here]
 * @param players
 * @param cards
 */
public static void playGame(int players, int cards) {
    if (players * cards > 52) {
        System.out.println("Not enough cards for that many players.");
        return;
    }
    boolean[] deck = new boolean[52];
    int[] playerScore = new int[players];
    for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
        System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1));
        int[] hand = Cards.dealHandFromDeck(cards, deck);
        Cards.printHand(hand);
        System.out.println("Score = " + Cards.pointValue(hand));
        System.out.println();
        playerScore[i] = Cards.pointValue(hand);
    }
    //go through playerScore array twice, first to find the highest score, then who has that score
}
```

Comment: What is stopping you from searching the web to find solutions to locating the largest value of an array?

Comment: it's a duplicate because no one helped me¿?

Comment: nothing was stopping me, i needed help being able to print multiple winners of the array instead of just one

Comment: yeah i wrote that comment smart guy. this is the only cse class i need, & i don't have the textbook so i get help online. someone on chegg helped me enough to where i could figure out the rest anyway, the code is below the only answer to this post as a comment, incase anyone else ever needs help with it. no thanks to this guy ^

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `playerScore`, comparing its value against a the maximum value till its previous iteration or 0, if it's iteration zero. If it's bigger, the maximum value is the iteration value.

```
int maximumValue = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < playerScore.length; i++) {
    if(playerScore[i] > maximumValue) {
        maximumValue = playerScore[i];
    }
}
```

To check the player with the maximum value you can use the same code snippet as before:

```
int maximumValue = 0;
long player = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < playerScore.length; i++) {
    if(playerScore[i] > maximumValue) {
        maximumValue = playerScore[i];
        player = i;
    }
}
if(player > -1) System.out.println("Player with highest score: " + (player + 1));
```

Comment: int highestScore = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < players; i++) {
System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1));
int[] hand = Cards.dealHandFromDeck(cards, deck);
Cards.printHand(hand);
System.out.println("Score = " + Cards.pointValue(hand));
System.out.println();
playerScore[i] = Cards.pointValue(hand);

if (Cards.pointValue(hand) > highestScore) {
highestScore = Cards.pointValue(hand);
}
}   
if (playerScore[i] == highestScore) {
System.out.println("Player " + (i + 1) + " is a winner");
}
}

Comment: to loop through the array twice ^